# How to add custom "-Djava" arguments to Grails app?

Tags: grails, command-line, jvm-arguments

Say I wanted to run a Grails (2.3+) app with an extra "`-Djava.fizz.buzz=3`" JVM arg.

Is it as simple as:

```
grails run-app -Djava.fizz.buzz=3
```

Or is there special config (say, in `BuildConfig.groovy`) that would need to take place?

Comment: If only there was a way you could try grails run-app -Djava.fizz.buzz=3 and see if it works. ;o)

Comment: Thanks @Gregg - I did and no exceptions/errors were thrown, and the app started up. But there's no real way for me to test with the arg got set or not, and the lack of error message and/or confirmation is unsettling...ideas?

Comment: @AdjustingForInflation you could easily test this by reading the arg and outputting it in the view/console/logs (or by setting a breakpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, that will work.  JVM args work a bit differently.  Both are in the docs about the [command line](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html).

Comment: that's not an answer

Answer (score 7):

That should work. And to have access to the arg you just created, you may call System.properties[] anywhere in your code:

```
if (System.properties['java.fizz.buzz'] == '3') {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grails -Djava.fizz.buzz=3 run-app
```